# Vue watch and display deep changes

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to display a message for each category the user is selected

```
<v-select multiple style="position: relative; top: 20px;" 
    color="white" v-if="count == 3 && question" solo placeholder="Please Choose" 
v-model="selected.category" :items="categories" item-text="name" return-object></v-select>
```

The user can select multiple categories, in each category there is a specific message i want to display.
I'm using watcher to watch the changes.

```
watch: {
            'selected.category': {

                handler(e) {
                    console.log(e)
                        this.icon = "mdi-emoticon"
                        this.text = this.selected.category.chat //This is an array now because multiple categories are selected
                        this.selection = true
                }
            },
}
```

The above code is wrong, it was only used when the user was able to select only one category, now i want them to be able to select multiple. I just can't figure out how to watch these deep changes and display the category message when multiple categories are selected. Is there any way i can send the latest selected category index in the handler or maybe only the selected object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This made it work.

```
 'selected.category': {

                handler(e) {
                    console.log(e)
                        this.icon = "mdi-emoticon"
                        this.text = this.selected.category[this.selected.category.length - 1].chat
                        this.selection = true
                }
            },
```